# how to pass http authentication headers in spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, oauth, authorization

I am working on customizing my spring boot authorization server. After login using username and password from the html page I have created I need to redirect back to /oauth/token endpoint ,in order to get the access token .
It is working fine while using postman. But when I give defaultsuccessurl as /ouath/token it shows me a default login page to enter username and password which the basic auth username and password from postman.
so, in order to get the access token from front end I need to add basic auth details as http header. I don't know where to add HTTP header and how to use that to get the access token after successful login using front end.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. One way is: along with html, you can use Javascript to set HttpHeaders and send the request. Below a sample code snippet (not complete though)

```
var user = "user1"; //ideally this should come from Input field in html page
var password = "MySecret";//ideally this should come from password field in html page

// var authorizationBasic = $.base64.btoa(user + ':' + password);
var authorizationBasic = window.btoa(user + ':' + password);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', oAuth.AuthorizationServer, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.send("<requestURL>");
```

Comment: Any working example available @charybr